# split line in tcl to create variables

Tags: split, tcl

I'm new to TCL, use it on occasions when required.

I need to read a file and extract some data, I have done the following see snippet below.

I can read the first line 22 but don't know how to split line in variables and extract the number `1300.85`. Similarly
extract number `1.283` from line 133 and `-1.338` from line 134.

Wonder if someone can help.

```
# Open file for reading
set input [open "Data.txt" r]

# # Code # #
set ln 0
while {[gets $input line] != -1} {
    incr ln
    if {$ln == 22} {
        set mass [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line]
        #[split $line "/n"]
    }
}
```

### Input Data

Read line number 22 from file (fixed line number) will give this:

```
Full mass               kg           1300.85
```

Read line number 132,133,134 from file  (fixed line numbers) will give these:

```
Base (P)       :            2.621 m         (respective to )
                     F:      1.283 m   A/K: +0.489681
                     R:     -1.338 m   R/K: -0.510319
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing the asterisks don't actually appear in your data. If you can figure out which line is which, this is easy. Let's say you store the three lines you want to work on in the variables `line22`, `line133`, and `line134`. Then you can get the values like this:

```
lindex $line22 3
# => 1300.85
lindex $line133 1
# => 1.283
lindex $line134 1
# => -1.338
```

This of course presupposes that the data on each line is a proper list, which the lines you provided are. If they aren't, you will need to `split` the lines first.

If you don't read line-by-line but instead read the whole file at once and split it into lines, you can access the values like this:

```
set f [open datafile.ext]
set data [split [chan read $f] \n]
chan close $f

set mass [lindex $data 21 3]
set fval [lindex $data 132 1]
set rval [lindex $data 133 1]
```

Normally you would `string trim` before splitting the lines, but that might change the line numbers in this case.

NB that this will only work as long as your file keeps the same basic contents, only changing the values in their places. Any added lines or added words on a line will make this extraction scheme useless.

Documentation: [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)

Comment: Thanks I was trying to split each line, didn't realise that it was quite straight forward. However when within the while loop, this seems to only work for the first line i.e. 22 does not seem to want to incremment to the other two lines.

Comment: @ArunM: I can't see from your example why this would fail. Reading the whole file and treating it as a list of lines like in Donal Fellows's answer would probably make things easier.

Comment: Hi Peter, I think I found my mistake, and now code works fine. Thanks for the help very much appreciated.

Comment: Good. As you wrote to Donal, using keywords to pinpoint values is a lot better than going for line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the file is truly enormous (hundreds of megabytes, or more), we are best reading it all into memory and then doing `split` on it by newline so that we can access the lines easily.

```
set input [open "Data.txt" r]
set lines [split [read $input] "\n"]
close $input
```

Then, we can pick the individual lines with `lindex`. There's a few way to parse them apart. In your case, we use *one* of the following techniques:

```
# With regexps (remember, Tcl indexes from zero):
regexp {kg\s([\d.]+)} [lindex $lines 21] -> value
```

```
# With regexps and list indexing:
set value [lindex [regexp -all -inline {\S+} [lindex $lines 21]] 3]
```

```
# With string format scanning (looking at how to extract the second value):
scan [lindex $lines 132] " F: %f m A/K: %f" value1 value2
scan [lindex $lines 133] " R: %f m R/K: %f" value3 value4
```

I think I might actually prefer `scan` for this sort of job, though I'd also want to look very carefully at other ways to get the data that wouldn't be vulnerable to extra lines being inserted.

Comment: Would you say that simply `lindex`ing out the values from the (proper-list) lines would be ill-advised? (I can of course see that there are advantages to your methods, but simplicity is also an advantage.)

Comment: Straight `lindex`ing the values out is fragile; if a line contains braces or double quotes, things will behave “strangely”.

Comment: But it should be valid in a case like this, then.

Comment: Gents, thanks for your help. I tried a few example and have come across some additional lines that make the code fall over. However the keys on each line are always the same therefore I should write a code that looks for key names and process the line rather than line number.